# Django Model delete foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have my Model `Config`, which contains a ForeignKey `PeriodicTask`.
I want to have an 1 to 1 relation, meaning that when I delete `Config` that `PeriodicTask` gets deleted and vice versa.

```
class Config(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
task = models.ForeignKey(PeriodicTask, default=None, null=True, 
                         blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Using `CASCADE` only my Config gets deleted, when PeriodicTask gets deleted but not vice versa. Also `PeriodicTask` belongs to an external module, so I don't have direct access to it.

How can I accomplish a 1 to 1 deletion relation?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5185684/4974980)

Comment: Oh yeah, that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

class Config(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  task = models.ForeignKey(PeriodicTask, default=None, null=True, 
                     blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def delete_task(sender,instance,using, **kwargs):
     instance.task.delete()


pre_delete.connect(delete_task, sender=Config)
```

instance is the instance of my Config object about to be deleted